# cant calculate sum of all inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I need to calculate the sum of all inputs and display it in the last input. I think the error is in "input.setAttribute ('class', '.qty1');". I assigned the class incorrectly, maybe I'm wrong. Everything worked until the bottom script was added. Please, help me.

```js
const names = ["Penny", "Howard", "Raj", "Leonard", "Sheldon", "Rajh"]

$(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
function inputs(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.setAttribute('for', names[i]);
        label.innerText = names[i];
        form.appendChild(label);
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.name = 'myInput_'+i;
        input.setAttribute('class', 'qty1');
        input.id = 'myInput_' + i;
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
 var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.name = 'myInput_';
        input.setAttribute('class', 'total');
        input.id = 'sum';
        form.appendChild(input);  
        document.getElementById('sum').disabled = true;  
}
```

```css
input { display: block; }
input.total { margin-top: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload = "inputs()"></body>
  <div id='myForm'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `.` from class name,  it `input.setAttribute('class', 'qty1');` and not `input.setAttribute('class', '.qty1');`